# Date incrementing constructor won't compile

Tags: java

The program is supposed to prompt a user for a date and it will increment by itself. It's the DateTest class that I'm having trouble with. The error message says "Cannot invoke nextDay() on the array type Date[]"

UPDATED

I got rid of the unnecessary statement. But now I'm getting this error message,

"Error: Main method not found in class Date, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)"

Do I have to move the main method anywhere?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Date {

    private int month; // 1-12
    private int day; // 1-31 based on month
    private int year; // any year
    int value;

    public Date() {
        month = 1;
        day = 1;
        year = 1900;
    }

    public Date(int m, int d, int y) {
        month = m;
        year = y;
        day = d;
    }

    public String GetDate() {
        String Msg1 = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Msg1);
        return Msg1;
    }

    public void setMonth() {
        int value = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Month:"));

        if (value > 1 && value < 13) // validate month  
        {
            month = value;
        } // check for leap year  
        else if (month == 2) {
            boolean isleap = true;
            if (year % 4 != 0) {
                isleap = false;
            } else {
                isleap = true;
            }

        } else // month is invalid  
        {
            String Message = "Month" + month + "Month must be 1-12";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Message);
        }
    }

    public void setDay() {
        int value2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Day:"));
        int[] daysPerMonth = {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};
// check if day in range for month
        if (value2 > 0 && value2 <= daysPerMonth[month]) {
            day = value2;
        }

        value = value2;
    }

    public void setYear() {
        int value3 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Year:"));
        year = value3;
    }

    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public int nextDay() {
        int cDay = day + 1;
        if (value == cDay) {
            day = cDay;
        } else {
            day = 1;
        }
        {
            NextMonth();
        }
        return day;
    }

    public int NextMonth() {
        if (12 == month) {
            year++;
        }
        return month = 1;
    }

    public String toString() {

        return month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

    }

}

class dateTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Date newDate = new Date(11, 27, 2011);
        final int arraySize = 1;


        {
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                newDate.setDay();
                newDate.setMonth();
                newDate.setYear();
            }
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {

                newDate.nextDay();

                {

                    String Message = "Incremented Date:" + newDate.toString();
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Message);
                        System.exit(0);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: this code will not compile, since newDate is declared twice

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean to do the below?

```
newDate[counter].nextDay();
```

The compiler is pretty clear on the problem. `newDate` is an array, you need to pick an element of the array to call the method on.

@ThaiTran Has hit on the actual problem.

You are defining the same symbol twice. If it works at all, I expect you want to call the method on the first one, but the compiler thinks you mean the second one.

```
Date newDate = new Date(11,27,2011);
....
Date [] newDate = new Date[arraySize];
```

Answer (score 1):

**For your updated error**

It is because the main method must be located in the public class, which in turn is the same name with the name of your java file. So, you must set the file name to `dateTest.java` and then, set the `public` access to dateTest class. Be aware that there is only one public class in one java file

Comment: *"Be aware that there is only one public class in one java file"* ... unless you're using inner classes ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want `dateTest` to work within the same file as `Date`, you can make it a `public static` inner class...

```
public class Date {

    /** Your Date Class Here **/    

    public static class dateTest {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            Date newDate = new Date(11, 27, 2011);
            final int arraySize = 1;


            {
                for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
                    newDate.setDay();
                    newDate.setMonth();
                    newDate.setYear();
                }
                for (int counter = 0; counter < 4; counter++) {

                    newDate.nextDay();

                    {

                        String Message = "Incremented Date:" + newDate.toString();
                        {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Message);
                            System.exit(0);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Basically, making sure that 1- it's `static`, 2- it's public and 3- it's within the class braces of the `Date` class...